# onPreview not working when click to previewIcon - Antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

According to the document [here](https://ant.design/components/upload/) it says callback function onPreview **will be executed when file link or preview icon is clicked**. But only the file link works for me. I can't figure out what is the problem here.

```
<Upload
  beforeUpload={() => false}
  listType="picture"
  maxCount={1}
  accept="video/mp4"
  onPreview={() => console.log("HELLO")}
 >
  <Button readOnly={someLogic} icon={<UploadOutlined />}>
   {t("admin_entity.add_video")}
  </Button>
</Upload>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used iconRender function to solve this problem

```
iconRender={(originNode) => (
 <PlaySquareTwoTone onClick={() => console.log("HELLO")} />
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

As i checked, the issue is come from file's thumbnail.

It works with with an image ( which can generate a thumbnail in list ).

Maybe you can try to override the thumbnail with some event listener on it, just a workaround solution :)

Comment: Can you provide some code? I'm new with antd and I don't know how to override the thumbnail